# Phonegap / Cordova - Code not playing audio on android (Not a path issue)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am working on a phonegap/cordova app which plays audio files stored locally.

I am having issues with some code and android where example 1 does not play on android and example 2 does play.

NOTE: The issues is not the path, I know that the path to the file is correct.

Example 1 - Does not play on android but plays fine on IOS where the path is modified for IOS.

```
var audiofile = cordova.file.dataDirectory+'android_asset/www/audio/1.aac';

 ...

 $( ".player" ).html('<div class="audioDemo-wrapper"><audio class="audioDemo" controls><source src="'+audiofile+'" type="audio/mpeg"></audio><div class="closeAudioBtn" onclick="stopAndCloseAudio();">X</div></div>');
 $(".audioDemo").trigger('play');
```

Example 2 - This works on Android but it's not the way I'd like to go.

```
var audiofile = cordova.file.dataDirectory+'android_asset/www/audio/1.aac';

 window.open(audiofile, '_blank', 'location=no,closebuttoncaption=Close');
```

The difference is mainly that Example 2 opens on a new window ?

Why does Example 1 not play on Android when it plays fine on IOS (Note: Paths are not the problem)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check this link http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/

May be It is helpful for you.

Comment: Something to consider - if your cordova plugin is trying to play natively, you might need to lookup the file's Uri from the MediaStore (a path won't work).

Comment: @Satch3000 I've reviewed you posts, it appears this is your first foray into Cordova. Is this correct? If so, Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using [CLI or SDK](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. (I assume not *Build*). Then, question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: @Satch3000 you say "paths are not the problem", but I see you are using the wrong paths. Can explain your logic why you think your "paths" are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Cordova webview on Android you can use:

1) **Audio HTML5 API** (also wrapped with jQuery) for playing **audio files from the web**.

2) **Cordova plugins** which provide APIs to play **local audio files** bundled with the Cordova project; for example two Cordova plugins to play audio files are:

- [cordova-plugin-media](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media)
- [cordova-plugin-nativeaudio](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio)

An alternative is to use [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) in a Cordova project, so replacing the native Cordova webview with the Crosswalk webview. This way you have a Chromium based webview, enabling support for all modern [web APIs](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/apis/web_apis.html), including audio.

Some useful mini-tutorials for Ionic/Cordova project (applying to only Cordova projects):

- http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-add-sound-effects-to-your-ionic-app-with-native-audio/
- https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/playing-audio-android-ios-ionicframework-app/

P.S.: unfortunately I wasn't able to find on Cordova docs details about web APIs supported by [Android Cordova webview](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/webview.html)